# Can I use use a set of transistors to 'select' from one or more capacitors

Tags: transistors, capacitor

I'm working with a monolithic audio amplifier IC that reads its gain setting from an RC network between two pins. The IC has fixed gain settings and the data sheet has a table specifying which resistor and capacitor values to use for each setting. I'm trying to make the gain setting selectable over I2C with a microcontroller. I think I did a similar configuration in the past with resistors but tbh it's been 20 years.[image: example diagram]

Comment: What device is the chip you are using - please link the data sheet.

Comment: The specific part is a TI TPA3128D2 2x30W Class D amplifier : https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3128d2.pdf . The gain setting lookup table is on page 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using an analog switch such as the CD4051. The switches have a bit of capacitance themselves and some resistance. For lower supply voltages (+/-5V or less) the 74HC4051 has less resistance. There are fancier analog switches that can handle higher voltages.

Comment: I was unaware of the existence of analog switches. turns out what I really want for this application is a CD4052B analog multiplexer. Using the multiplexer lets me reduce my number of control lines from 38 to 4 and use a single micro-controller to manage all the amps

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use use a set of transistors to 'select' from one or more
> capacitors

Yes, but you should use MOSFETs instead of BJTs.  While BJTs can work for grounding a resistor, its going to cause problems for a capacitor.  The reason is that the capacitor needs to have current flow both ways, but a BJT doesn't normally do that.

An appropriate MOSFET part number might be something like 2N7002

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution since the discharge through the internal diode of the MOSFET is not controlled and may alter the requested behavior. Analog switches give the expected result.

Comment: @PaulGhobril JFETs might be a workable option as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do something broadly similar but using LH1518AAB photomos parts from Vishay, they have usefully low capacitance and acceptable on state resistance.

It is worth placing a megaohm or so across the switching device to minimise switch clicks when changing taps.

The other workable approach is to use jfets but that tends to suffer from annoyingly high channel resistance in the on state and poor linearity at high signal levels. Charge injection can also be an issue with this approach.